# ReactJS How can I map an Obj from API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, jsx, instagram-api

I try to get images from Instagram and build a gallery on my site.

myCode:

```js
function Instagram() {
  const instagramData = async () => {
    const url = `https:/site.com/...`;
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const feed = await data.json();
    console.log(feed);
  };

  instagramData();

 return (
    <>
      {feed.map((feed) => {                 //it's not feed :(
        return (
          <div key={feed.id}>
            <img src={feed.media_url} alt="" />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export default Instagram;
```

my Array from console:

```
{data: Array(25), paging: {…}}
data: Array(25)
0: {id: '123', media_url: 'https://stuff.com/1', permalink: 'https://www.instagram.com/p/1/'}
1: {id: '456', media_url: 'https://stuff.com/2', permalink: 'https://www.instagram.com/p/2/'}
....
length: 25
[[Prototype]]:Array(0)
paging
: 
{cursors: {…}, next: 'https://website/abcd'}
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

'feed' is not the right var to use. But somehow i must extract the array from the function and store it like a normal obj. But how?

What magical code I need to do the .map ?

Comment: `{data.data.map((feed) => {` can solve your issue? What does your `data` object look like?

Comment: data.data.map((feed: any) => {...}  _TS2304: Cannot find name 'data'_

Comment: What does your data object look like exactly?

Comment: @DreamBold don't know: just got it from the console, just copied and shorten it.

Answer (score 2):

Call the function `instagramData()` inside `useEffect` hook

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';

useEffect(() => 
  instagramData();
},[])
```

[solution link](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-kowalevski-t3so1i?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Also, I think you should use `useState` ( `const [images, setImages]`) and set the state of the "images" that you want to handle.

Comment: with your url it's working, but not with mine :(  my link is working, because i get some data in my console.log

Comment: Instagram.tsx:28 Uncaught TypeError: feed.map is not a function

Comment: Yes, that's because you declared the feed variable inside the function InstagramData() so now feed is a local variable and you're calling it from outside so you're having this error. In order to solve that you need to use useState hook like in the example in the link that I shared

Answer (score 2):

Please implement `useState` hook to store feeds, and make your API call inside `useEffect` hook.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Instagram() {
  const [feeds, setFeeds] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
      const instagramData = async () => {
        const url = `https:/site.com/...`;
        const data = await fetch(url);
        const feeds = await data.json();
        setFeeds(feeds);
      };
      instagramData()
    }, []);
    return (
      <>
        {feeds.map((feed) => {
           return (
            <div key={feed.id}>
              <img src={feed.media_url} alt="" />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </>
    );
}
export default Instagram;
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: feeds.map is not a function is my rsult. i tried the link from Muhammad Allak it's working, but not with my instagram link :(

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Code:

```js
function Instagram() {
  const [feeds, setFeed] = useState<any[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const instagramData = async () => {
      const url = `https://graph.instagram.com/v15.0/me/media?fields=id,media_url,permalink&access_token=${process.env.REACT_APP_INSTAGRAM_KEY}`;
      const data = await fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
      // const feeds = await data.json();
      console.log(data);
      setFeed(data);
    };
    instagramData();
  }, []);
  // console.log(feeds)
  // console.log(Object.values(feeds));
  return (
    <>
      {Object.values(feeds)[0]?.map((d: any) => { //use it as Obj, nested Obj
        return (
          <div key={d.id}>
            <img src={d.media_url} alt="" />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export default Instagram;
```

[image: Screensho Array Console]